is there a geth node snapshot?
I have run geth for a week, but the state download progress is slow.
The logs like:
INFO [04-09|01:24:18.711] Syncing: chain download in progress      synced=71.37% chain=285.21GiB headers=14,007,024@6.17GiB bodies=13,971,012@186.74GiB receipts=13,971,012@92.30GiB eta=529h22m17.127s
INFO [04-09|01:24:19.264] Syncing: state download in progress      synced=0.46%  state=1.92GiB accounts=1,904,291@260.90MiB slots=7,715,741@1.62GiB codes=14887@53.90MiB eta=17h29m9.682s

Is there a geth node snapshot which can be download? Thank you.

I run geth use --syncmode snap. The state download is very slow.

It maybe just your internet speed but I believe I succeded to pass those two steps (chain and state download) in under 14 hours. I have 1Gb internet speed.
I would just to check if your connecting to enough peers (are the port for execution and concensus client open and accessible from outside ? for execusion client geth, the default peer port is 30303).

./geth --mainnet  --snapshot --authrpc.addr "localhost" --authrpc.jwtsecret "${JWT_DATA_DIR}/jwt.hex" --authrpc.port 8551 --http --http.addr 0.0.0.0 --http.port 8545 --http.corsdomain ""  --http.api admin,debug,web3,eth,net --ws --ws.addr 0.0.0.0 --ws.port 8546  --ws.origins "" --ws.api admin,debug,web3,eth,net --datadir ${GETH_DATA_DIR} --datadir.ancient ${GETH_ANCIENT_DATA_DIR} --discovery.v4 --discovery.v5 --maxpeers 100 --port 30303 --discovery.port 30303 --gcmode "full" --history.state 1000 --history.transactions 1000  --state.scheme "path" --syncmode "snap"

On another note, I also use the following options to run my full node (some of them might be the default values and some of them need to be adapted if running an archive node) and I use ligthhouse as my concensus client (was using prysm before).
